# Align a parent div to center of the responsive page that has left align childs

Tags: css

I have a responsive page that has this section:

```
<div id="team">
    <div class="person">
        <div class="photo"></div> 
        <div class="title"></div> 
    </div>
    <div class="person">
        <div class="photo"></div> 
        <div class="title"></div> 
    </div>
    <div class="person">
        <div class="photo"></div> 
        <div class="title"></div> 
    </div>
    <div class="person">
        <div class="photo"></div> 
        <div class="title"></div> 
    </div>
    <div class="person">
        <div class="photo"></div> 
        <div class="title"></div> 
    </div>
</div> 


#team {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
#team .person { 
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: left;
    cursor: default;
    margin: 0 3em;
}
```

`team` has 100% width. I need to align `team` to center of the page depend on page width. But children `person` should be align to left inside the `team`.
So when we have some `person` that not fill a row, it should be align to the left.
Can you please help?

Comment: Well first of all you don't need to give them all a class of person. Do something like `.team div`. It will save a lot of code. Also, please make a fiddle depicting your problem

Comment: @Cody - `.team div` will also select the children `<div>` tags within the `.person` div.  So his code is correct.  He could use `.team > div` to ensure it's a top level `<div>`.  Although I prefer using direct class selectors for compatibility reasons (IE6).

Answer (score 1):

`margin: 0 auto;` really only works on fixed width elements.  You cannot expect a div set at 100% width to be centered with it.

If you're wanting to center the contents of `#team`, you can simply apply `text-align: center;`.  This will apply to your `.person` divs since you set them as `display: inline-block;`

Check out the results of `text-align: center;` here to see if it's what you're looking for: http://jsfiddle.net/Chs9X/

Comment: Good, but i need to align `person`s that not fill a row to left. (They are center now on your example.) like a grid lines... how can i do that?

Comment: To left align it to the edge while maintain the centering aspect, you're going to have to define a width.   If you know the static width of `.person`, you could make your `#team` width equal to `3 X .person width + margins` and apply `float: left` to `.person`.  If you want it to expand and change it's width to be dynamic, you'll most likely have to introduct some `@media queries` to handle the various scenarios.